# How to access a global javascript module in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have created a global module (we use javascript, we don't use node or angular, it's a pure javascript code) and my module looks like this:

```
var ComponentsModule = (function (kendo) {
    var addLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent = null;

    return {
        getAddLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent: function() {
            return addLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent;
        },
        registerAddLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent: function(component) {
            addLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent = component;
            kendo.bind(component.modal, kendo.observable(component.viewModel));
        }
    };

})(kendo);
```

It works fine, but in jasmine it's undefine. How do I access my module in Jasmine?

```
describe("Components", function () {
    describe("ComponentsModule: ", function() {
        it("Should register AddLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent", function () {
            // Arrange
            var module = ComponentsModule; // undefined

            // Act
            module.registerAddLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent();

            // Assert
            expect(module.getAddLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent()).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
})
```

We use Resharper for now to run the tests, so it automatically references the dependecies (I guess, as up to now all tests have ran, excepttests for modules)

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I get to the solution ([reach the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/w1usxb7x/15/)), I'd like you to note my assumptions:

- You are instantiating the `ComponentsModule` with some predefined
  `kendo`/`k` variable somewhere before I suppose like I did in my code
  here (because your code is working as you noted above)
- If your test code is in another js file, like a spec, then make sure you have your dependency `(ComponentsModule)` gets instantiated even before the script runs.
- Your `module.registerAddLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent` from test `it` should actually take in a param if you are evaluating it to be `toBeDefined` further in your expectation. (Based on your source code)

  ```
  var kendoVariable = {
   observable: function(mdl) {
    return "mdl";
   },
   bind: function() {
    console.log("binded");
   }
  };
  var ComponentsModule = (function(kendo) {  
    var addLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent = null;

    return {
      getAddLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent: function() {
        return addLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent;
      },
      registerAddLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent: function(component) {
        addLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent = component;
        kendo.bind(component.modal, kendo.observable(component.viewModel));
   }
  };

  })(kendoVariable);

  describe("Components", function() {
    describe("ComponentsModule: ", function() {
      it("Should register AddLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent", function() {
    // Arrange
       var module = ComponentsModule; // undefined

    // Act
       module.registerAddLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent({
        modal: "some modal",
        viewModel: "some view model"
       });

    // Assert
      expect(module.getAddLieferbilanzkreisModalComponent()).toBeDefined();
    });
   });
  });
  ```